# What if I don't really hate hats that much after all?

Tags: support, winterbash

I have some questions about hats.

I have noticed an "I don't like hats" link, I'm assuming that clicking this prevents me from collecting hats... so I didn't click it. Is this correct?

Hypothetically, if I did click it, could I unclick it?

Comment: The real question is how do you get unusuals and can you sell them for large amounts of cashdollars?

Comment: Talk about editing my question and changing its fundamental meaning! mod abuse! MOD ABUSE! *I WON'T BE SILENCED THAT EASILY!*

Comment: @pixel Just re-ask the question he edited out as another question! Ha! That'd show him!

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yeah, until the pro-hat agenda *deletes them*! It happens, I saw it on a blog on the internet!

Comment: Just flag one of @badp's post and ask for a ban, I'll do it... I'll do it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click *I hate hats*, you can easily re-activate it by clicking the Winter Bash link on the top left corner of the page (that doesn't disappear), which will pop-up this window

[image]

Comment: And I believe you still get hats for the period you hated them, if you earned any.